# Whats wrong with my html/php form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I want to have a form on my we bsite but i know nothing about php, so i found some template on google. I copied and put it on my website but when i try to test it shows the messege that its been sent succesfully but nothing appears on my e-mail.

```
        <div id="center">
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">first name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
 <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">last name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">email</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">phone number</label>
</td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">more information</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 <input type="submit" value="L&auml;het&auml;"> 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Heres the php code. Note that i seriously have no experience on php and i just found this template from google. Only things i have edited my email and emails subject. Also, i replaced my email with myemail@myemail.com

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to = "myemail@myemail.com", $email_subject
= "somone actually used the contact form", $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thanks for contacting.

<?php   
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting random code from the internet and hoping it will work, how about taking some time to actually learn PHP?

Comment: Did you look in your spam folder for the message?

Comment: Are you actually sending the message?

Comment: Depending on where your website is hosted, it may not actually send an email.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
<?php
$to      = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$subject = 'Message Subject';
$message = 'Message Text';
$headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: someone@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

The e-mail you send could be in the spam box, though.